# Call a batch file from GVim

Tags: batch-file, vim

I made a simple batch file to evaluate command line arguments passed. The file looks something like this:

```
:: cl-calc.bat
@echo off    
set /a value=%*
echo %value%
```

I put this into my C:\Windows\System32\, so when I use the command line I get this:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>cl-calc 32*2
64
```

And this is great. But when I try to call it from Vim, (using **!cl-calc 32*2**) I get an error

> 'cl-calc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

So I try some other things, like:

```
!cl-calc.bat 2+2
!call cl-calc
let result = system( 'cl-calc 32*2' )
let result = system( 'call cl-calc 32*2' )
```

I've even done this:

```
!cmd.exe
C:\Windows\System32>cl-calc 2+2
```

And above pertinent variants. All of these have gotten the same error as before. When I do

```
C:\Windows\System32>dir /OD
```

it says the last modified file was modified days ago (5, to be exact). When I do this in the regular command line it shows my file as one of the most recently edited.

So what's going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me Gvim is a 32-bit program, and it is looking at the SysWOW64 folder instead of System32.  The **former** is 32-bit and the latter is 64-bit, confusingly enough.  And yes, [Windows *does* lie to 32-bit programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx) and tell them they're looking at System32 when they're actually looking at SysWOW64.

Comment: Do your psychic powers tell you how I can fix this? (Aside from putting a copy inside SysWOW64, my other guess would be to reinstall GVim as 64 bit? (As a side note, it's in Program Files (x86))

Comment: @DavisDude, you could put the script to some non-system directory (`C:\Windows` might work), which is in your `%PATH%`. Maybe use the directory where your GVim is located, just add it to the `%PATH%` variable in system settings.

Comment: @xaizek That would work, for some reason it slipped my mind that there are more paths it can go to.